# Unable to get channels using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

while fetching channels from the team using graph API is not working. It is not working from today. I am getting the following exception.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA1Qv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by the Microsoft Graph team. Now it's working fine. It's not the only problem with channels. It's a problem with team endpoint API. The graph team is fixed the API related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with code that worked just fine 3h ago to get channels from a specific team. Now I'm getting the same exception. Same Exception when using Graph-Tester.

Coworker tried it aswell with Graph-Tester, apparently it works just fine for her. Seems like its user related. Propably a bug on Microsofts side.

Comment: can I know what is the role for you and your colleague? like you have teams admin and she was global admin.

Comment: I am global admin, she was just a member. Tried it later with another colleague which is also global admin. Worked for him. 

Today is works for me again without a problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it could be a bug. I'm confirming that right now GET /teams/[-groupid-]/channels fails for Delegated permission type requests, both for v1.0 & beta with a 400 Bad Request "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest." 
However, it's working for me (200) when I use Application permission type in Postman.